# Elementos en CSS no se centran

Tags: html, css

El problema es que los elementos que quiero centrados son 4 imágenes con un pequeño texto debajo de ellos pero no se centran, utilice CSS para intentar alinearlos pero no me lo permite, se ve bien en móviles pero no en escritorio. Les agradecería mucho que me orientaran en esto. Aquí esta el código html y CSS

```
    <section id="options">
        <h3>Selecciona una opción</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <img src="../Imagenes/AltaUsuarios.png" alt="">
                <h4>Dar de alta usuarios</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="../Imagenes/BajaUsuario.png" alt="">
                <h4>Dar de baja usuarios</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="../Imagenes/ActualizarUsuario.png" alt="">
                <h4>Actualizar datos de los usuario</h4>
            </div>
         <div>
                <img src="../Imagenes/BuscarUsuarios.jpg" alt="">
                <h4>Buscar datos de los usuarios</h4>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </section>

#options .container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap; /* Para que los elementos que no caben vayan abajo 
  */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes proceder de este modo:

**Explicación**

- Aplicas un `display: flex;` al contenedor principal de todos los nodos que sería la etiqueta `body`
- Ahora que el contenedor `body` hace a sus elementos flexibles, entonces podemos hacer una alineación vertical y horizontal con `justify-content: center;` y también con `align-items: center;`
- Puedes englobar en un etiqueta `article` tanto a la etiqueta `img` como a la etiqueta `h4` para poder manipular ambos contenidos
- Para poder hacer una alineación primero horizontal aplicamos a los nodos con las clases `.options .container` un `display: flex;`ya que deacuerdo con la especificación<sup>1</sup> todo el acomodo será horizontal sobre el **main axis**
- Para el caso de las imágenes que deseas aparezcan justo arriba del texto descriptivo de cada uno, puedes aplicarle un `max-width: 100%;` eso provocará que se ajuste en sus dimensiones a máximo el 100% del ancho de su contenedor padre y no descuadre tu maquetación
- A la etiqueta `article` le aplicamos un `padding` de `10px` para separar el contenido del margen de su contenedor padre
- A la misma etiqueta `article` le aplicamos un `text-align: center;` para acomodar el contenido
- Finalmente ahora para mantener el acomodo de elementos ya hecho pero solo cambiar la orientación de los elementos, aplicamos en una *media query* un `flex-direction: column;` que provocará que todos los elementos se apilen uno sobre otro

Código:

```html
    <style>
      body{
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
      }
      .options .container {
        display: flex;
      }
      article{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .img{
        max-width: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      article:nth-child(even){
        background-color: red;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .options .container{
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <section class="options">
      <div class="container">
        <article>
          <img class="img" src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
          <h4>Título 1 de la imagen</h4>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img class="img" src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
          <h4>Título 2 de la imagen 2</h4>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img class="img" src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
          <h4>Título 3 de la imagen 3</h4>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img class="img" src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
          <h4>Título 4 de la imagen 4</h4>
        </article>
    
      </div>
    </section>
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [FlexBox Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)